# How to get the body content of a web page returned in an API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, restsharp

The response from an API is web page with full HTML and CSS content. The only thing I want is the content in the body.

How can I extract the body content from the web page?

Below is the short version of the web page. The page is very long I can't post everything here.

The body content I want to extract is " Hi John, Doe wishes you a happy anniversary and wants all of us at FCMB to wish you same, Congratulations on your anniversary Doe"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif;}
        .general-container {min-height: 100vh; border-radius: 6px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="CustomerPreviewMsg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">
                        <div class="row mx-0 col-12 profile-pic-container">
                            <p class="pt-3">
                                Hi John, Doe wishes you a happy anniversary and wants all of us at FCMB to wish you same, Congratulations on your anniversary Doe
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/JsFile/MainJs.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
```

This is the code that is consuming the endpoint

```
var client = new RestClient(appSettings.ShoutOutPreviewUrl + previewMessage.MessageHistoryId);
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", appSettings.ShoutOutToken));
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
IRestResponse<string> res = client.Execute<string>(request);

return res.Content;
```

Comment: Is this static html pages or dynamic? If dynamic are you using razor to render the view?

Comment: Its only the body content that is dynamic. The html is static

Comment: So are you render using razor engine? What does the original view looks like? Again I am assuming that you are using MVC or Razor view pages.

Comment: When I preview the page in the browser, it's like a modal, I didn't create the API. I am just consuming the API to get the dynamic content from my asp.net core. I am supposed to display the content in a reactJs modal. I think it's better to extract the content and display in frontend modal

Comment: Use an XML parser.  If the path to the node you want to extract is static between calls to the endpoint then you should be able to easily pull it out with an XPath query.

Comment: @squillman how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I used HtmlAgilityPack to get the node https://html-agility-pack.net/
I installed via nuget

```
internal string ParseHtml(string Html)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(Html);

            var htmlNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class='pt-3']");

            string rawText = htmlNodes.InnerText.Trim();

            return rawText;
        }
```

Comment: could this work?If works good, you can set it as an answer

Comment: Yes, it works. it's already an answer or how do I set it as an answer?